# Ruby : line.include?"#{varStrTextSearch}"

Tags: ruby

I have a file **ImageContainer.xml** with text as follow:

```
<leftArrowImage>/apps/mcaui/PAL/Arrows/C0004OptionNavArrowLeft.png</leftArrowImage>

<rightArrowImage>/apps/mcaui/PAL/Arrows/C0003OptionNavArrowRight.png</rightArrowImage>
```

Now, I am searching for `C0004OptionNavArrowLeft.png` and `C0003OptionNavArrowRight.png` in that file.

Code is:

```
@LangFileName = "ZZZPNG.txt"
fileLangInput = File.open(@LangFileName)
fileLangInput.each_line do |varStrTextSearch|

    puts "\nSearching ==>" + varStrTextSearch

    Dir.glob("**/*.*") do |file_name|
        fileSdfInput = File.open(file_name)
        fileSdfInput.each_line do |line|
            if line.include?"#{varStrTextSearch}"
                puts"Found"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

here `varStrTextSearch` is string variable having different string values.

Problem is that is it is finding `C0004OptionNavArrowLeft.png` but not finding `C0003OptionNavArrowRight.png`.

Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It could be that `varStrTextSearch` is not 'OptionNavArrow' at some point in your code. What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: *"varStrTextSearch is string variable having different string values"* - please explain that, where do these different values come from, i.e. how does your code get invoked?

Comment: @LangFileName = "ZZZPNG.txt"

fileLangInput = File.open(@LangFileName)
 fileLangInput.each_line do |varStrTextSearch|
 
  puts "\nSearching ==>" + varStrTextSearch
  
  Dir.glob("**/*.*") do |file_name|
   fileSdfInput = File.open(file_name)
   fileSdfInput.each_line do |line|
    if line.include?"#{varStrTextSearch}"
     puts"Found"
    end
   end
  end
 end

Comment: I am iterating through a file having different strings and varStrTextSearch is string variable which store that string values one after other.

Comment: @Prashant please edit your question instead. Longer snippets of code within a comment are unreadable.

Comment: BTW, in Ruby we use snake_case for methods and variables (and CamelCase for classes and modules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, newline chars are the problem.

```
fileLangInput.each_line do |varStrTextSearch|
```

`varStrTextSearch` here will contain a `\n` char at the end. And if your XML is not consistently formatted (for example, like this)

```
<leftArrowImage>
  /apps/mcaui/PAL/Arrows/C0004OptionNavArrowLeft.png
</leftArrowImage>
<rightArrowImage>/apps/mcaui/PAL/Arrows/C0003OptionNavArrowRight.png</rightArrowImage>
```

Then your problem can be reproduced (there's no newline char after "C0003OptionNavArrowRight", so it can't be found).

Solution? Remove the unwanted whitespace.

```
fileSdfInput.each_line do |line|
  if line.include? varStrTextSearch.chomp # read the docs on String#chomp
    puts"Found"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Sergio... varStrTextSearch.chomp is working fine.

Comment: Accept the answer then. And for the future, when asking questions, provide code/data with which we can reproduce the problem, without having to resort to guessing. It's called an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).